# How to create Key-Value RDD (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, key, rdd

I have the following RDD (name: AllTrainingDATA_RDD)  which is of type 
**org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double, Double, String)]** :

```
(ICCH_1,4.3,3.0,Iris-setosa)
(ICCH_1,4.4,2.9,Iris-setosa)
(ICCH_1,4.4,3.0,Iris-setosa)
(ICCH_2,4.4,3.2,Iris-setosa)
```

1st column : *ICCH_ID*, 2nd column: *X_Coordinates*, 3rd Column: *Y_Coordinates*, 4th column: *Class*

I would like to end up with an RDD which has **2nd and 3rd column as the Key** and **4th column as Value**. The column ICCH_ID should remain in the RDD.

My currently attempt based on some Internet research is this:

```
val AllTrainingDATA_RDD_Final = AllTrainingDATA_RDD.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(X_COORD,Y_COORD)).mapValues(fields => ("CLASS")).groupByKey().collect()
```

However I get this error:

> error: value split is not a member of (String, Double, Double, String)

P.S. I am using Databricks Community Edition. I am new to Scala.

Comment: I would recommend you to start by taking a simple Scala tutorial. Your code have a lot of simple syntax errors. I believe the [**Tour of Scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) should be enough. Also, have a hand the **Scaladoc** of both, the [`stdlib`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.8/) as well as the [`Spark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#package) one. Finally Google is your friend. - PS: The error is pretty clear to me, your RDD is of tuples, tuples do not have a split method, and your field access are bad too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tottaly agree with you! I will pay attention to the tutorials you pointed me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to break down your solution, part by part:

```
val AllTrainingDATA_RDD_Final = AllTrainingDATA_RDD
    .map(_.split(","))
    .keyBy(_(X_COORD,Y_COORD))
    .mapValues(fields => ("CLASS"))
    .groupByKey()
    .collect()
```

You first problem is the use of `.map(_.split(","))`. This is likely a preprocessing stage done on an `RDD[String]` to extract the comma separated values from the text input lines. But since you've already done that, we can go ahead and drop the part.

Your second problem will come from `.keyBy(_(X_COORD,Y_COORD))`, and it's going to look something like this:

> error: (String, Double, Double, String) does not take parameters

This is because you supplied `keyBy` an anonymous function that attempts to apply `(X_COORD,Y_COORD)` on each of the tuples in your RDD, but what you actually want is function that extracts the x and y coordinates (2nd and 3rd values) from your tuple. One way to achieve this is `.keyBy{case (_, x, y, _) => (x, y)}`

Lastly, your use of `mapValues` just produces the same String value `("CLASS")` for all elements in the RDD. Instead, you can simply take the 4th value in the tuple like so: `.mapValues(_._4)`

Putting this all together, you get the following code:

```
val AllTrainingDATA_RDD_Final = AllTrainingDATA_RDD
    .keyBy{case (_, x, y, _) => (x, y)}
    .mapValues(_._4)
    .groupByKey()
    .collect()
```

Since you are new to Scala, I suggest you take some time to get aquatinted with syntax, features and APIs before you continue. It will help you understand and overcome such problems much faster.

Comment: I really apreciate your complete and usefull answer. I know that your last point is the most important and I will pay attention to your advices. Before that thought one last question : I realised when I printed the RDD that you helped me create, that the Column ICCH_ID is missing. I would like to have the column still there. Is this possible?

Comment: @ArisKantas where should it remains? As part the value?

Comment: As part of the final RDD. Is it possible to take it as part of the Value? Or there is a way to make it seperated? I need to make some computations based on that column afterwards and I will have to extract this information into a List.

Comment: @ArisKantas It can not be separated, it has yo either be part of the key or of the value. I would assume that in the value is the best alternative. Then you only need this instead `mapValues { case (id, _, _, class) => (id, class) }`.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! That worked. In fact it gave me a better understanding of how to use these functions. Thank you so much.